# Application Error in Twilio voice call Django/python

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I have started to use Twilio Voice call recently for sending OTP to users using Django.
I am referring to the given link to customise the Twilio response.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/python/flask

**views.py**

```
def voice_call(otp, mobile_no):
    client = TwilioRestClient(settings.ACCOUNT_SID, settings.AUTH_TOKEN)
    client.calls.create(from_=settings.OTP_FROM_NUMBER,
                        to=mobile_no,
                        url='http://localhost:8000/outbound/',
                        method='POST')


def outbound(self):
    response = twiml.Response()
    response.say("Thank you for contacting our department",
                 voice='alice')
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/xml")
```

In urls.py, I have /outbound/ that points to my django view module.

If I hit '/outbound/' in browser it renders the correct xml response 
but in the voice call, it gives an error message saying **'Sorry application error'**

Not sure where i am going wrong in rendering the xml.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the problem is that you are trying to point Twilio to your `localhost`. When Twilio connects the call, it will try to make an HTTP request to the URL you pass in the REST API call. If you pass `localhost` then Twilio won't be able to reach it as that is only available on your machine.

There is a solution though! We recommend using a tool called [ngrok](http://ngrok.com). It allows external services to tunnel through to your `localhost` so that you can test webhooks like this. Check out these blog posts on [how to set up ngrok for use with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html) and [all the reasons I like using ngrok for developing with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks @philnash for the suggestion. I was little occupied with the other stuff so I couldn't respond sooner.
I tried with ngrok and gave permissions to the URL from my Twilio account but it is still giving me the same error.
I also looked into logs where it is showing me this error
**11200 HTTP retrieval failure**
I am not sure where is that coming from. Could you please guide me a little as I am completely a newbie in this.

Comment: You say that when you load the XML in browser it works, which is a GET request. Is your phone number in Twilio set to GET or POST?

Comment: It is set to POST.. I just realized it was a csrf issue which was forbidding it from making a request to Twilio.
I have used crsf_exempt for that. It is working now.
Although I am not able to access my session variable now.. but I guess i will figure out a way to do that.

Thanks a lot for your time and help.